# Unable to read pixels from bitmap using Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, bitmap, xamarin

I thought trying to get pixel data would be a simple thing to do, but it has become a big headache.

My original goal is to go through every pixel in the bitmap and then do some modification with the data. However every time I try to get the pixel I get 0 as a result. It feels like the image is not going to the bitmap. Am I missing something in my code or the code in general wrong?

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)

{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);


        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var imageView1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        imageView1.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.pic1);

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources,Resource.Drawable.pic1);
        b = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(b);

        imageView1.SetImageBitmap(b);

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {

                int pixel = b.GetPixel(i, j);

                int A = Color.GetAlphaComponent(pixel);
                int R = Color.GetRedComponent(pixel);
                int G = Color.GetGreenComponent(pixel);
                int B = Color.GetBlueComponent(pixel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is Resource.Drawable.pic1 ?

Comment: It's the image in the Drawable folder

Comment: so use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`

Comment: I'm still getting 0 as a result used imageView1.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources,Resource.Id.imageView1));

Comment: use SetImageResource instead, so whats actually your problem ImageView or getPixel ?

Comment: Ok, after taking a break and rethinking everything I rewrote the code and everything works now. Thanks pskink!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources,Resource.Drawable.pic1);
```

Comment: Please add more details. At this moment this answer is a low-quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            Color pixel = new Color(b.GetPixel(i, j));

            int A = Color.GetAlphaComponent(pixel);
            int R = Color.GetRedComponent(pixel);
            int G = Color.GetGreenComponent(pixel);
            int B = Color.GetBlueComponent(pixel);
        }
    }
```